# Caesar Cypher with Python

Tags: python, encryption

I've been trying to make a simple Caesar Cypher lo learn a bit more about Python but I can't get right. The encryption part seems to work but I can't reverse the encryption properly to get the right output. Can someone tell me what is wrong with my code? 
Thanks in advance.
R.

```
text = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ :)"

key = 12

coded_text = ""

for n in text:
    if n.isalpha():
        index = ord(n) + key 
        if n.isupper():
            if index > ord("Z"):
                coded_text += chr(index-26)
            else:
                coded_text += chr(index)
    else :
        coded_text += n


decoded = ""

for n in coded_text:
    if n.isalpha():
        index2 = ord(n) - key 
        if n.isupper():
            if ord(n) + 26 > ord("Z"):
                decoded += chr(index2+26)
            else:
                decoded += chr(index2)
    else :
        decoded += n

print
print "Original Text:"
print text
print
print "Encrypted Text:"
print coded_text    
print   
print "Decrypted Text:"
print decoded
```

Comment: you can use mod function instead of subtracting, no need of using ord here as your are using upper alphabet and u already checked its alpha or not, you suing key 12, so it means you shoud shift the letter by 12

Comment: Terminology nitpick: it should *encoded_text*, not *coded_text* ;)

Answer (score 1):

In python is would  probably use `string.maketrans`

```
>>> import string
>>> letter = string.lowercase
>>> def ceaser(n):
...     return string.maketrans(letter,letter[n:]+letter[:n])
... 
>>> enc = ceaser(3)
>>> "hello".translate(enc)
'khoor'
```

for decoding: send -ve key

```
>>> dec = ceaser(-3)
>>> 'khoor'.translate(dec)
'hello'
```

Comment: Fine, but this is not what I am asking.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, in the decoding step, the n.is_upper condition automatically prevents all other characters from being decoded as you do nothing to them.

Comment: Sorry, but this is not the problem in the code. If the line "#if n.isupper():" is commented the code will still not decrypt properly.